# Instantiation of a module in verilog

Tags: module, instantiation, verilog

I am getting an error in instantiating a module in verilog file. I am instantiating like this:

```
module lab3(input clk,set,reset,plus,minus,start,button,output reg [3:0]led,output reg [6:0]y);

wire [3:0] indicesgu[3:0];
reg [1:0] going;
reg alsogoing,yes;


if (going==1 && alsogoing)
begin
 up_counter up_0 
 indicesgu  ,
 indices    ,
 alsogoing
 );
end
```

and my up_counter module starts as:

```
module up_counter(input [3:0] indices_in [3:0],output [3:0]indices[3:0],output alsogoing);

reg [3:0]indices[3:0];
reg [2:0]current,setting;
```

when I try to compile in Xilinx, it says unexpected token up_counter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your `lab3` module.

1. You need an `endmodule` at the end.
2. You should not instantiate `up_counter` inside an `if`. Verilog does not support conditional instances like that.
3. You need an opening paren after the instance name `up_0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have (multiple) syntax errors in your code.
One of them is you need brackets () around your component port list

```
up_counter up_0 (indicesgu  ,
                 indices    ,
                 alsogoing
                 );
```

check the [Verilog syntax](http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html#REF79) for more info.

This will at least fix the 'unexpected token up_counter' error.

Comment: Thanks. But it still says unexpected token up_counter. Actually, both of these modules are in two different files. I have added both of them as sources, but for some reason Xilinx does not recognize that one of them is being used in another.